# How to explain the presence of a dependency, akin to `yarn why`?

Tags: ruby, bundler

[yarn](/questions/tagged/yarn)has a `why` command, to **explain the presence** of a dependency:

```
time yarn why @babel/highlight
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "@babel/highlight"...?
info Reasons this module exists
   - "eslint#@babel#code-frame" depends on it
real    0m0.330s
```

How can I do this in [bundler](/questions/tagged/bundler)?

### Requirements

1. *simple* - a simple command akin to `yarn why` would be ideal, but I'll also accept a short ruby script or small gem
2. *fast* - solution must be roughly as fast as `yarn why` (< 1s)
3. *constrained to bundle* - must not print gems that are **outside the bundle**, as `gem dependency` does)

### What I have tried

- `bundle why` - there is no such command
- I reviewed the [list of `bundle` commands](https://bundler.io/docs.html) and saw nothing relevant
- There used to be a command `bundle viz` but it was removed and there's [no official replacement yet](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/3333). Also, it's not exactly what I want; it creates a *visual* representation of the *entire* graph. It may be possible to use one of the two unofficial replacements to generate a `.dot` file, and parse that, but .. seems like there should be an easier way.
- `gem dependency tzinfo --reverse-dependencies` is close, and useful, but is not limited to the `Gemfile` (ie. it will print installed gems that are not part of the bundle)

Comment: How about looking at your `Gemfile.lock`?

Answer (score 2):

I have written a bundler plugin, [bundler-why](https://github.com/jaredbeck/bundler-why) for this.

```
bundler plugin install bundler-why
```

```
bundle why tzinfo
ransack -> activesupport -> tzinfo
rspec-rails -> activesupport -> tzinfo
business_time -> tzinfo
...
```